# How to make Material UI TextField responsive on zoom in and zoom out?

Tags: html, css, reactjs, material-ui

In my first ever Material UI project, I am facing responsiveness issue with **TextField and SelectField**.

I am developing my application at 1920px width screen size, so page is looking fine on this resolution, but when I am trying to lowering the screen width, it seems that TextField and SelectField are getting bigger and looking very odd on the screen.

**screen at 1920x-**
[image]

**screen at 1423px**
[image]

**screen at 1024px**
[image]

at 1024px width, form is occupying approx. the whole screen. I just want to control textField height and width according to the screen resolution.

Like we use to do with normal bootstrap form media queries, is there any way to apply CSS media query or any other way?

Please help.

I have created one sample App on code sandbox below is the link-

https://codesandbox.io/s/jrzq2m?file=/ResponsiveForm.jsx  or  https://jrzq2m.csb.app/

**Note- I am using <kbd>ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>+</kbd> and <kbd>ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>-</kbd> to change resolution and also tried from chrome inspect element mobile responsive.**

Comment: It looks perfectly responsive to me for all screens. In smaller screens, it should occupy more space that's what everybody wants. Why does it look odd to you?

Answer (score 0):

Hope this helps!

> useMediaQuery

from `Material UI`

```
import {useMediaQuery} from '@mui/material'

const responsive = useMediaQuery("(max-width:960px)");
```